# What assemblies are loaded by default when you create a new ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application Project?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

What assemblies are loaded by default when you create a new ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application Project ?

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest thing be to just create a new web app project and look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a list of loaded assemblies in the current application domain using `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` to see everything that's loaded

```
        Assembly[] loadedAssemblies = 
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in loadedAssemblies)
        {
            Response.Write(assembly.FullName);
            Response.Write("<br />");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The ones you reference plus the mandatory ones like : mscorlib, System, System.Web, System.Xml
To check which assemblies are referenced in a new web application, check the References subfolder in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

```
System
System.Configuration
System.Data
System.Drawing
System.EnterpriseServices
System.Web
System.Web.Mobile
System.Web.Services
System.XML
```